# The term 'System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to get the Pull Request ID but keep getting
The term 'System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber' is not  recognized as a name of a cmdlet
I have also tried System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber but same error

Im using Azure devops pipleine yaml file and the repo is in Github

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    #write-host $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
    write-host $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the `pr` trigger (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers))?

I've created a repo in github and here is my sample pipeline (In Github as well)

```
pr:
- main

steps:
- powershell: Write-Host "$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)"
```

I've configured the pipeline from Azure Devops and when I create a PR targeting the main branch, it runs successfully:
[image]